# Catching forked subproceses

Tags: linux, process

I'm running a game in wine that requires pasuspender to kill pulseaudio so the game can run on alsa.

However, it looks like the script and wine itself are forking separate processes so that pasuspender ends early.

No response:

```
$ pasuspender -- sleep 10s
$
```

When running game:

```
$ pasuspender -- wine dxhr.exe
Connection failure: Connection terminated
$
```

And then the process continues to run in the background of the terminal.

Comment: I don't remember `wine` going to the background ever.